# Java implementation of 2 dimensional interval tree

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, interval-tree

I need a 2 dimensional interval tree for storing rectangular regions in a canvas.
I need to identify the regions which contain the point clicked or the regions overlapping with a rectangular selection.

Is there any standard implementation of 2 dimensional interval tree for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that [R-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) or it's variants are suitable.

Implementation may be found [here](http://www.rtreeportal.org/)

Edit: Now `rtreeportal.org` site does not work ([2005 snapshot](http://archive.li/bcKsW)), but seems there is no comparable aggregator site that contains information and implementations for different kinds of R-trees.

Comment: the second link has no thing to do with r tree, is that a mistake? btw I have not downvote this but I am also wondering why this is accepted as answer if the link does not work?

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ Five-years old link is dead. It is tedious.. but happens. (In that time rtreeportal contained a lot of useful material and implementations for different kinds of r-trees)